# Office 365 Unified API Exchange folders

Tags: ms-office, office365

I'm starting to look at the new Office 365 Unified API (specifically around Exchange for the moment).

In the existing Mail API at you can make an authenticated call to https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/folders/Inbox/messages in order to get messages in the Inbox. You can also hit `folders/Drafts/messages`, `folders/SentItems/messages` and `folders/DeletedItems/messages` to retrieve messages from Drafts, Sent Items and Deleted Items respectively. This is documented at https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/mail-rest-operations#AllMailAPIoperations.

Problem is, I can't find (either in documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/HowTo/office-365-unified-api-reference#msg_ref_relationship_Messages or by messing about on https://graphexplorer2.azurewebsites.net) how to drill into these folders when accessing via the Office 365 Unified API.

The documented URL to access messages via the new Unified API is https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/Messages, and so I was hoping I could hit something like `Messages/Inbox` or `Messages/folders/Inbox`, but no luck so far.

Does anyone know if these paths are currently missing or addressed differently, or if it's the intention that you find what you want by using `$search` rather than drilling into specific folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having checked back (and read through https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata) this has now been implemented. You access folders via `MailFolders/[folder name]/messages`, so:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/MailFolders/Inbox/messages`
`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/MailFolders/Drafts/messages`
`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/MailFolders/SentItems/messages`

..etc.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't currently supported in Unified API, but is high on our priority list, and we are working on it.  Sorry for the confusion.  You can continue to use outlook.office365.com endpoint for now, to access folder info.

Comment: The unified API /messages currently maps to the inbox folder, as Venkat mentioned above, is high on the list to add folders.